# nowait doesn't seem to work

Tags: key-bindings

Well, I have had these cases before. I sometimes did unmap, but I don't want to do this for every case.

I define

```
nnoremap <nowait> <leader>h :wincmd h<CR>
```

But it does wait for me typing longer normal commands after the `\h`.
Is it because they are defined afterwards?

`map \h` returns the following:

```
n  \hp          @<Plug>(GitGutterPreviewHunk)
n  \hu          @<Plug>(GitGutterUndoHunk)
n  \hs          @<Plug>(GitGutterStageHunk)
x  \hs          @<Plug>(GitGutterStageHunk)
n  \h          * :wincmd h<CR>
```

What is the meaning of the * btw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<nowait>` is intended for cases where a global mapping `\hs` (for example) exists and you would like to create a buffer-local mapping `\h` (for example).

I suppose then the following would work:

```
autocmd FileType * nnoremap <nowait> <buffer> <leader>h :wincmd h<CR>
```

In `:map`, `*` means created with `nnoremap` etc, i.e., "not re-mappable."